# How to use a read/write stream between two Python asyncio coroutines?

Tags: python, pipe, python-asyncio

How can I use asyncio to implement a pipe between two coroutines, one that reads from a stream and the other that writes into it?

Suppose we have this existing code, two simple scripts. One that produces to stdout:

```
# produce.py

import asyncio
import random
import sys

async def produce(stdout):
    for i in range(10000):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 3))
        print(i, file=stdout, flush=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(produce(sys.stdout))
    loop.close()
```

And the other that reads from stdin:

```
# consume.py

async def consume(loop, stdin):
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader(loop=loop)
    reader_protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
    await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: reader_protocol, stdin)

    while True:
        line = await reader.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print(int(line) ** 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(consume(loop, sys.stdin))
    loop.close()
```

Obviously, since our two pieces can run individually from the command-line, we could use the `subprocess` module with shell pipes (`produce | consume`).

But we would like to implement the equivalent of a Unix pipe in Python, i.e. connect the streams of those two existing functions.

Something like this won't work:

```
pipe = io.BytesIO()

await asyncio.gather(produce(pipe),
                     consume(loop, pipe))
```

If the two functions would manipulate generators, we could write something like this (python 3.6):

```
async def produce():
    for i in range(10000):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 3))
        yield str(i)


async def consume(generator):
    async for value in generator:
        print(int(value) ** 2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(consume(produce()))
    loop.close()
```

Is there some parts of the asyncio API that would allow that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A way of fixing this, is to turn your current functions into generator and to write some wrappers to expose them with Unix pipes:

```
# wrapper.py

import asyncio
import random
import sys


async def produce():
    for i in range(10000):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 3))
        yield str(i)


async def consume(generator):
    async for value in generator:
        print(int(value) ** 2)


async def system_out_generator(loop, stdout, generator):
    async for line in generator:
        print(line, file=stdout, flush=True)


async def system_in_generator(loop, stdin):
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader(loop=loop)
    reader_protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
    await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: reader_protocol, stdin)
    while True:
        line = await reader.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        yield line


async def main(loop):
    try:
        if sys.argv[1] == "produce":
            await system_out_generator(loop, sys.stdout, produce())
        elif sys.argv[1] == "consume":
            await consume(system_in_generator(loop, sys.stdin))
    except IndexError:
        await consume(produce())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

You can either use:

```
python wrapper.py  # Python generators
```

or:

```
python wrapper.py produce | python wrapper.py consume  # System pipes
```

Comment: This assumes the stream data is newline-separated text.

Comment: In our case that was the way to always get a full line, but I guess you could use `read(1024)` instead if you want a binary stream.

Answer (score 1):

The original post says "Something like this won't work." I'm not sure if this statement is indented to mean "the following code did not work" or "I do not want a solution of this style."

I will note that the following code does work:

```
r, w = os.pipe()
read_pipe = os.fdopen(r, 'r')
write_pipe = os.fdopen(w, 'w')

await asyncio.gather(produce(write_pipe), consume(loop, read_pipe))
```